# Complex has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, one-to-many

This is a brain teaser for me, but hoping it's clear to someone more experienced. Having trouble sorting out the correct associations.

I have three models:
User, Recipient, Discussion

Right now the associations are set up this way:

Discussion

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :recipients
```

User

```
has_many :discussions, dependent: :destroy
has_many :discussions, :through => :recipients
```

Recipient

```
belongs_to :user, dependent: :destroy
belongs_to :discussion, dependent: :destroy
```

When I try to create a discussion with this action in the discussions_controller:

```
def create
  @discussion = current_user.discussions.build(params[:discussion])
  @discussion.sent = !!params[:send_now]

  if params[:subscribe_to_comments]
    CommentSubscriptionService.new.subscribe(@discussion, current_user)
  end

  if @discussion.save
    redirect_to @discussion, notice: draft_or_sent_notice
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

I get this error:

```
Could not find the association :recipients in model User
```

I have not yet created the action for saving recipients.

Hoping your answer will help clear the cobwebs for this first issue, which is the association, then I'll move on to the next. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the error is correct; you're missing the recipients association in the `User` model.

Your user model needs to know about the recipient model in order to use `has_many :through`

Try adding this to your user model:

```
has_many :recipients
```

Edit:  Actually, from your question, I'm not entirely sure how you want the models to be laid out.  You should also only be calling `has_many :discussions` once in your user model.

How are your tables laid out?  Did you mean to do this for User: `has_many :recipients, :through => :discussions`?

Edit 2:

Alright, from your comment, I don't think that the user needs to have many recipients.  So on a basic level, just remove the second line to make your user model look like:

```
has_many :discussions, dependent: :destroy
```

You may also need to remove the `belongs_to :user` in your recipient model.

Comment: It's confusing. Basically, what I want is for discussion to have one user who is the leader of the discussion, then I want that leader to be able to invite many users and that's why I set up the recipients model. Not sure if that's the best way to do this, but I'm open to your suggestions. I've never done something this involved with the user model being used in two different ways.

Comment: I updated my answer to explain how to get rid of your current error, but I'm going to post another answer on a potential way to design this system.  I'm no expert, so it will just be my thoughts on the matter :)  Your solution definitely seems like it could work though.

Comment: Would be great to hear an alternative, Ryan. I think it could be done without the recipient model, but I just don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Another potential solution would be to outline your models like this:

```rb
class Discussion
  has_many :participants
  has_many :users, :through => :participants

  def leaders
     users.where(:leader => true) # I think this should work: http://www.tweetegy.com/2011/02/setting-join-table-attribute-has_many-through-association-in-rails-activerecord/
  end
end


class Participant
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :discussion
  # This class can have attributes like leader, etc.
end

class User
  has_many :participants
  has_many :discussions, :through => :recipients

  def leader?(discussion)
    participants.find_by(:discussion_id => discussion.id).leader? # doesn't seem super elegant
end
```

With this solution, all of the users are kept together as participants in the discussion, rather than having one leader with multiple recipients.  After implementing some of it though, I'm not sure how neat it turned out :P I'll go ahead and post it, but you should make the informed decision yourself.

I'm no expert; this is just another alternative to how you have your models laid out.  Let me know if you have any questions.  I hope this helps!

Comment: Okay. that helps, I think we're getting closer based on your feedback, but I also think we need to start over with another question as my original question is now not as relevatn. I'm going to create another question and I'll point you to what I've created.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17622827/using-the-user-model-twice-in-an-association-with-discussion-with-a-leader-and-p