# Creating multiple participants in the User model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, associations, has-many

I'm trying to set up a complex association where the User model is used two times. Once to create the leader of a discussion and then to create the participants for the discussion.

First, do I have the associations correct in order to call multiple participants (users) for a discussion led by one user (leader)?

User

```
has_many :discussions, foreign_key: :leader_id
belongs_to :received_discussions, class_name: 'Discussion'

attr_accessible :participant_id
```

Discussion

```
belongs_to :leader, class_name: 'User'
has_many :participants, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :participant_id
```

And second, how would I build the action to assign multiple users as participants?

Form:

```
  .offset2.span7.mtop20
    = simple_form_for @discussion, html: { multipart: true } do |f|
      %fieldset.well
        .mtop10
          = f.input :participant_ids, label: 'Send to: (select from members you follow)', as: :select, collection: participants_for_discussion, input_html: { class: 'followed-ids-select', multiple: true }
          = f.input :title
          = f.input :description
        .form-actions
          = f.submit 'Send', name: 'send_now', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-large pull-right mleft10'
          = f.submit 'Save and View Draft', name: 'save_draft', class: 'btn btn-large pull-right'
```

discussion_controller

```
def create
  #not sure how to assign the participants in the action
  @discussion = current_user.discussions.build(params[:discussion])


  if @discussion.save
    redirect_to @discussion, notice: draft_or_sent_notice
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

The error I'm getting is `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: participant_ids`

Comment: have a look at http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many?view=comments

Answer (score 1):

First of all you want to have has_and_belongs_to_many between User and Discussion, both when a user is a leader or participant.

First you should make the decision if you want to user habtm or has_many :through association
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many

Then remodel your associations and the rest of your problems should solve themselves.

Comment: Hey Michael, I have read that I should steer clear of HABTM, but with regard to has_many through: I started to create it this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17621313/complex-has-many-through-association then changed directions to arrive at the above solution. Having a hard time wrapping my head around this, so more information would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Where you read that? It depends on what you have to model - if an association has params of it's own habtm may be useful. And if you wish to avoid it there's still `has_many :through`

Comment: Brian, above is no a "solution" as it's plain wrong! You can't have many-to-many relationship with `belongs_to` on one side!

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. There seems to be no consensus on best practices for this kind of association: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15960573/rails-how-to-write-create-action-in-habtm-model-controller

Comment: Ah, I wrote stupid thing above. I was to say that if an association will have any own attributes one shoud choose `has_many :through`. Personally I also think it's a better choice as it is more flexible.

Comment: Thanks, now at least I've narrowed down my options. That helps.